# How to filter in datastore using objectify for a Date property ?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

How to filter  in datastore using objectify for a Date property ? 
I have a entity which looks like below pojo class . In this timeStamp is a property which holds the Date value.

```js
public class TravelEntry {
    private String deviceId;
    private String pushedGeoData;
    private String location;
    private Date timeStamp;

    public TravelEntry(){
        setTimeStamp(this.timeStamp);
    }

    public String getDeviceId() {
        return deviceId;
    }

    public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }


    public String getPushedGeoData() {
        return pushedGeoData;
    }

    public void setPushedGeoData(String pushedGeoData) {
        this.pushedGeoData = pushedGeoData;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Date getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(Date timeStamp) {
        if(timeStamp==null){
            this.timeStamp = new Date();
        }else{
            this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        }

    }


}
```

How do I query or filter the Date property  using Objectify ?
I want retrieve all entity those are of particular date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all spelled out in the documentation:

https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Queries

`@Index` the field and then filter by the desired date value.